# In microservices with jhipster, when i use UAA Server, the user entity is in the database of UAA server or Gateway?

Tags: jhipster

I'm reading about of UAA server, and have one doubt...
If i have a project with microservices (MS), with:

- UAA server
- MS type gateway (using UAA authentication)
- MS type application (using UAA authentication)

I understand that the **UAA server**, creates *User entity* in your own database (for example db_uaa), but my doubt is born when i think about the **MS gateway**.

The **MS gateway** too creates another *User entity* in your own database (db_gateway) or the **MS gateway** no creates *User entity* in your database (db_gateway), because it uses the UAA authentication.

I hope you can help me to clarify this doubt, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users are stored on UAA side only.

The Gateway which supports the client side (i.e., authentication and user-management) will access to users through some exposed UAA services.

If you need to access to the user entity from another microservice, look at the @Feign concept.

Hope this helps.